# How to sscanf with negative float?

Tags: c, string, parsing, scanf

Actually I have a string with this type:

> "1,Hello,E025FFDA,-126.56,52.34,true"

And I want to parse it using sscanf to store those value in variable of corresponding type so

> uint, char[], maybe string here, ufloat ?, float, bool

I use sscanf with `"%[^',']"` format specifier and I test each value if it is correct or not and in a certain range.

Here is my code:

- param is the pointer to the beginning of the string
- temp2 a temporary variable
- local_ptr is a copy of param to not modify param
- RCV a struct with all my parameters

```c
if((get_param_length(param) != 0) && (sscanf(local_ptr, "%[^',']", &temp2) == 1))
    RCV.binarypayload = temp2;
else
    error = 1;
```

Do you have any idea of the best type to store my values? Or maybe any advice?

Comment: A negative float is just `float`

Comment: float numbers are best stored in 'float' or 'double' types

Comment: What is `%[^',']` supposed to do? Do you mean `%[^,]`?

Comment: In most scenarios I encounter usage of floating point is unnecessary anyway and can be replaced by fixed point arithmetics instead (consider currencies where you could use the sub units instead, e.g. cents instead of euro or dollar, or fix fractions of). If that's an option for you you might read in two integers instead and calculate final result from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no type that could match your `ufloat`. All floating point types are signed so extracting from your string could be done like this:

```
#include <math.h>     // if you want to use fabsf()
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    unsigned u1, u2;
    char str1[20], boolstr[6];
    float f1, f2;
    const char *local_ptr = "1,Hello,E025FFDA,-126.56,52.34,true";
    bool b;

    if(sscanf(local_ptr, 
       " %u,%19[^,],%X,%f,%f,%5s", &u1, str1, &u2, &f1, &f2, boolstr) == 6)
    {
        b = strcmp(boolstr, "true") == 0;
        printf("%u %s %X %f %f %d\n", u1, str1, u2, f1, f2, b);
    }
}
```

Possible output:

```
1 Hello E025FFDA -126.559998 52.340000 1
```

If you want to get the absolute value from `f1`, just add `f1 = fabsf(f1);` after the `sscanf`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `"1,Hello,E025FFDA,-126.56,52.34,true"` is the string you want to parse, you can do it like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char string[] = "1,Hello,E025FFDA,-126.56,52.34,true";

    unsigned int i;
    char s1[10]; // You can adjust the size here and update it in sscanf()
    char s2[10];
    float f1, f2;
    char s3[10];
    
    if (sscanf(string, "%u,%9[^,],%9[^,],%f,%f,%9s", &i, s1, s2, &f1, &f2, s3) != 6)
        printf("Error parsing\n");
    else
        printf("%u, %s, %s, %f, %f, %s", i, s1, s2, f1, f2, s3);
}
```

This will output:

```
1, Hello, E025FFDA, -126.559998, 52.340000, true
```

If you want to store `"true"` in a `bool`:

```c
bool b = !strcmp(s3, "true"); // else false
```